# FormatException: Could not find any recognizable digits

Tags: c#

I get this exception:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

At this line:

```
String value = "2";
uint? test = Convert.ToUInt32(value, 2);
```

Comment: Are you sure the problem is on this line? Post complete code.

Comment: Please Explain more.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's because your second parameter sets the base to 2, and 2 is not a valid digit in binary.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swz6z5ks(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1)

> The call to `public static uint ToUInt32(string value, int fromBase)` will throw a `FormatException` when `value` contains a character that is not a valid digit in the base specified by `fromBase`. The exception message indicates that there are no digits to convert if the first character in value is invalid; otherwise, the message indicates that value contains invalid trailing characters.